# Error 0x8004159D while loading data from PostGIS to ArcGIS Pro

Tags: postgis, postgresql, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, import

I successfully connected to the PostgreSQL database, and I can see the tables/data. When I load one of the data (linestring data) it works well. But when I loaded the polygon data it prompted the error

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004159D

What I did was dragging the `spatial.public.adm_xxxx_ar` as highlighted in the picture. what does this error mean? how do I load my polygon data?

[image]

This is how I imported the shapefile into the `PostGIS` database. I made sure that the SRID is [WGS UTM zone 48S which has an EPSG code of 32748](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-48s/).

[image]

Comment: This is now 7 months old.  Did you ever get it fixed?  I'm in the same boat and ESRI is struggling to figure out what is happening?  I sucessfully loaded a PostGIS point layer but no luck with polygons or lines.

Comment: @jport Hi, no I don't have any updates, sorry. will update asap if I have.